# Cropped posts on mobile version of Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The mobile version of the site sucks on my Android phone (Firefox 44 on Android 5.1.1). Quite often posts' contents are cropped from the right side which makes them practically unreadable. And zooming out doesn't work.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Stack Overflow can't HTML]

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Can reproduce on an Android tablet as well. Maybe the image is causing the issue? Firefox on iPhone (which of course uses the system rendering engine and not its own) does not exhibit this behaviour; it does shrink the images down considerably though.

Comment: Have seen the same thing happen in Firefox on Android. This makes a mobile version of site pretty much unusable. Not sure, if this has anything to do with any images, the behavior is consistent for me.

Comment: The official answer you're going to get is probably 'use the Android/iOS app'.

Comment: Quick 'n dirty "fix": toggle [Desktop view/mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-change-desktop-view-firefox-android) and at least you finally can read it...

Comment: @cybermonkey But what if the app sucks even more? I prefer the mobile site very much to the Android app. Why does Android get no love? The iOS App is much better...

Comment: @XaverKapeller Be glad you don't need to use windows phone app. The buttons to login through google or facebook don't even respond... Site is pretty much the only option for me

Comment: Same site issue on Windows Phone.

Comment: hey, I'm Paweł - guy working in SO, i've reproduced this bug and will fix it in coming days. thanks for reporting that issue.

Comment: @Paweł it'd be much more visible if you posted this as an answer. It would also let the OP accept it, showing the question has been resolved.

Comment: @River i will post it as answer once it's fixed :)

Comment: Ah ok. Sounds good =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This issue has been fixed. It's now usable in Firefox :)